# Pass HTML5 Data Attribute as argument in function

Tags: javascript, html, oop, custom-data-attribute

I am looking to pass a HTML5 Data Attribute to an argument using Javascript. My problem is that if I pass a value to the argument it doesn't go looking for that specific value but is instead already set from the global variable.

So for example I have a component with

```
data-request="Five"
```

I want to be able to pass

```
requestResponses.init('URLHERE', 'Five');
```

and target the element with Five Only so the selector would become

```
.cp_trafficLight[data-request="Five"] .cp_trafficLight_Light--greenDimmed'
```

Currently I am just grabbing the HTML5 Data Attribute value and targeting that with

```
targObj = $('.cp_trafficLight').data("request");
```

I know this is probably a simple answer but I can't seem to crack it. All my code is posted below and I will also post a fiddle for visual purposes.

```
targObj = $('.cp_trafficLight').data("request");

var requestResponses = {

    targSel: '.cp_trafficLight[data-request=' + '"' + targObj + '"' + ']' + ' ',
    greenLight: '.cp_trafficLight_Light--greenDimmed',
    redLight: '.cp_trafficLight_Light--redDimmed',
    greenBright: 'cp_trafficLight_Light--greenBright',
    redBright: 'cp_trafficLight_Light--redBright',

    settings: {
        flashError: 400,
        requestTime: 10000
    },

    init: function (url, targObj) {
        requestResponses.url = url;
        requestResponses.getResponse(requestResponses.url);
        setInterval(function () {
            if (requestResponses.errorCode === true) {
                $(requestResponses.targSel + requestResponses.redLight).toggleClass(requestResponses.redBright);
            }
        }, requestResponses.settings.flashError);
    },

    successResponse: function (targObj) {
        requestResponses.errorCode = false;
        $(requestResponses.targSel + requestResponses.redLight).removeClass(requestResponses.redBright);
        $(requestResponses.targSel + requestResponses.greenLight).addClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
    },

    errorResponse: function (targObj) {
        $(requestResponses.targSel + requestResponses.greenLight).removeClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
    },

    getResponse: function (serverURL) {
        $.ajax(serverURL, {
            success: function () {
                requestResponses.errorCode = false;
                requestResponses.successResponse(targObj);
            },
            error: function () {
                requestResponses.errorCode = true;
                requestResponses.errorResponse(targObj);
            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    requestResponses.getResponse(requestResponses.url);
                }, requestResponses.settings.requestTime);
            }
        });
    },

    errorCode: false
}

requestResponses.init('status/index.html', 'Two');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/co6w6m2L/

Comment: What's the problem? What is it that goes wrong? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: There are no answers but say for example I have two of the above components it always targets the same one when I want them both to be targeted separately. So I can Pass the attr value in the argument and target that one specifically. I will update my question.